# How do I run a conditional statement "only once" and every time it changes?

Tags: python, while-loop

I might be asking a simple question. I have a python program that runs every minute. But I would like a block of code to only run once the condition changes? My code looks like this:

```
# def shortIndicator():
a = int(indicate_5min.value5)
b = int(indicate_10min.value10)
c = int(indicate_15min.value15)
if a + b + c == 3:
  print("Trade posible!")
else:
  print("Trade NOT posible!")

# This lets the processor work more than it should.
"""run_once = 0  # This lets the processor work more than it should.
while 1:
    if run_once == 0:
        shortIndicator()
        run_once = 1"""
```

I've run it without using a function. But then I get an output every minute. I've tried to run it as a function, when I enable the commented code it sort of runs, but also the processing usage is more. If there perhaps a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. If you mean print only when the result changes, add another variable which remembers the previous result and examine that too in the condition.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to just print when the result changes. Else I get a result every 60sec. Like so: Trade NOT posible!
Trade NOT posible!
Trade NOT posible!
Trade posible!
Trade posible!
Trade posible!
Trade posible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not clear what you mean, but if you only want to print a notification when the result changes,  add another variable to rembember the previous result.

```
def shortIndicator():
    return indicate_5min.value5 and indicate_10min.value10 and indicate_15min.value15

previous = None
while True:
    indicator = shortIndicator()
    if previous is None or indicator != previous:
        if indicator:
            print("Trade possible!")
        else:
             print("Trade NOT possible!")
    previous = indicator
    # take a break so as not to query too often
    time.sleep(60)
```

Initializing `provious` to `None` creates a third state which is only true the first time the `while` loop executes; by definition, the result cannot be identical to the previous result because there isn't really a previous result the first time.

Perhaps also notice the boolean shorthand inside the function, which is simpler and more idiomatic than converting each value to an `int` and checking their sum.

I'm guessing the `time.sleep` is what you were looking for to reduce the load of running this code repeatedly, though that part of the question remains really unclear.

Finally, check the spelling of *possible.*

Comment: Thanks tripleee. That seems to run. I'll let it run on the exchange just to make sure.

Comment: There is something I don't understand about this line: return indicate_5min.value5 and indicate_10min.value10 and indicate_15min.value15
All 3 these values must equate to "3". If one of them is "0" then it must run the else statement: print("Trade NOT possible!")

Comment: Your code seems to assume each of the returns either 0 or 1, and adds their sum. If you want to check that *one of them* is true, use `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: Oh. Now I get what it does. I have tried to print the "return" statement because one of the returns where 0 and it still showed Trade Possible.But if all 3 indicators returned a 0 would that not also give a True statment?

Comment: Ok. I've tried it. I even changed the line "if indicator:" to if indicator == 1: .  It does not seem to come out of the loop. (Fixed the spelling of possible)

Comment: Probably edit your question to clarify these variables. If their sum is really the deciding factor, then do add them together and examine the sum. I obviousy had to guess several things here, which makes it harder to answer, and harder for you to decide when an answer is useful enough to be acceptable.

Comment: My apology. I'm actually Afrikaans so my choosing of words are not always correct. Allow me just to think of a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can save previous output to a file, then read it at the beginning of program and print output only if previous output was different.

Comment: Unfortunately the 1minute updates must take place to fetch data from the server. The file is called ever 60 sec to check if there is a change. But that makes it a line every 60 sec.

Comment: I do not really understand. You can delete content of the file before you wtote to it again.

Comment: I've got lots of csv's functioning already, but I'd prefer to run it while I'm there for the reason that it also indicates that the bot is working.

Comment: You do say that you run your program once per minute, which seems to suggest that you are looking for a way to save state between runs. Your comments here again leave more for us to guess than they clarify anything.

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I'm unclear. English is not really my first language, That program runs once per minute and I end up with a print statement every minute. Mostly they are the same statement. If this works I will replace the print statements to other code. Say and email or a telegram message. It is sort of an On-Change effect that I'm looking for.

Comment: It could be a good idea to write it to a file and keep it as a timestamp log.